# Mixing a PHP variable with a string literal

Tags: php, string, variables

Say I have a variable `$test` and it's defined as: `$test = 'cheese'`

I want to output `cheesey`, which I can do like this:

```
echo $test . 'y'
```

But I would prefer to simplify the code to something more like this (which wouldn't work):

```
echo "$testy"
```

Is there a way to have the `y` be treated as though it were separate from the variable?

Comment: by `$test = cheese;` you meant `$test = 'cheese';`  at the end your post (if I am not wrong)...

Answer (score 313, accepted):

```
echo "{$test}y";
```

You can use braces to remove ambiguity when interpolating variables directly in strings.

Also, this doesn't work with single quotes. So:

```
echo '{$test}y';
```

will output

```
{$test}y
```

Comment: is it also possible to inline function calls with such a method? Something similar to `"foo{implode(',', [abc])}bar"`

Comment: @velop Nope. Building strings is often done after processing has occurred. Calling functions in the middle of preparing your output it often not what you want. Consider calling the function first, storing the result in a variable and then you can include it in the string `echo "like so: $var";`.

Comment: how to embed a ternary operator that evaluates to two diff strings in a string?

Answer (score 60):

You can use `{}` arround your variable, to separate it from what's after:

```
echo "{$test}y"
```

As reference, you can take a look to the [**Variable parsing - Complex (curly) syntax**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) section of the PHP manual.

Comment: Thanks. I tried reading the strings manual but wasn't sure exactly what I was looking for to search it for what I was after.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Yeah, not always easy to find the right section, when you don't really know what you're searching for ^^

Comment: Worth noting that once you're inside the {}, you can use expressions, not just variable names, such as {$x->y[3]} or whatever.

Answer (score 8):

Example:

```
$test = "chees";
"${test}y";
```

It will output:

> cheesy

It is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`"${test}y"` is [deprecated since PHP 8.2](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/$%7Bvar%7D-string-interpolation-deprecated), use `"{$test}y"` instead. (Note the `$` being covered by the curly braces.)

Answer (score -2):

```
$bucket = '$node->' . $fieldname . "['und'][0]['value'] = " . '$form_state' . "['values']['" . $fieldname . "']";

print $bucket;
```

yields:

```
$node->mindd_2_study_status['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']
['mindd_2_study_status']
```