# str_replace unexpected behavior

Tags: php, str-replace

I am writing a trivial templating system for running dynamic queries on a server.

I originally had the following code in my templating class:

```
$output = file_get_contents($this->file);

foreach ($this->values as $key => $value) {
    $tagToReplace = "{$key}";
    $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
}
```

I notice that the strings were not being replaced as I expected (the '{}' characters were still left in the output) .

I then changed the 'offending' line to:

```
$tagToReplace = '{'."$key".'}';
```

It then worked as expected. Why was this change necessary?. Does "{" in an interpreted string have special significance in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. When using double quotes, `"{$key}"` and `"$key"` are the same. It's usually done so you can expand more complex variables, such as `"My name is: {$user['name']}"`.

You can use single quotes (as you have), escape the curly brackets -`"\{$key\}"`- or wrap the variable twice: `"{{$key}}"`.

Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does help to resolve variable names. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-php-variable-with-string-literal).

`{` and `}` can used as follow:

```
$test = "something {$foo->awesome} value.";
```

By the way, you can further improve your code by using the following (and thus avoiding the situation you're having right now):

```
$output = file_get_contents($this->file);
$output = str_replace(array_keys($this->values), $this->values, $output);
```

Comment: you forgot an anonymous function to wrap keys in {}!