# Sending link with php variables using PHPMailer

Tags: php, html

I want to send an email that lets you reset your password on our webshop. Because we needed to implement some type of security feature. Everytime you request to get your password changed we update a token in our database. This token plus your email will need to be sent to you in form of a clickable link.

I tried using http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=echo$token&email=echo$email with the proper php tags. But the result I get is: 
http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=echo$token&email=echo$email. And not http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=1&email=2. I believe this happens because I want the link to be in a variable itself like $body = href='http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=echo $token&email=echo $email' again with the proper html and php tags

Does anyone know how to add the variables to the link?

`<?php`
$token = 1;
$email = 2;

`$body = '`

    `<h1>Wachtwoord wijzigen</h1>`

`<body>
    <p>Druk op de link hieronder om uw wachtwoord te wijzigen.</p><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=<?php echo $token?>&email=<?php echo $email?>">Klik hier</a>`
';

Comment: Can you post the actual code, the solution is straight-forward but easier if you provide your unworking code.

Comment: How do you add code to your post without it becoming al messed up?

Comment: Use the til key, to the left of the number 1 on your keyboard, use it at the start and at the end of your code.

Comment: Is this running from a .html file or a .php file?

Comment: a php file in phpstorm

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
echo 'http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=' . $token . '&email=' . $email;
```

Without seeing your actual code it's hard to give you code you can copy and paste, but the above is how you would escape a string to include a PHP variable.

[Click here for more information about escaping strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555758/escape-string-with-php-and-html/27555967)

Answer (score 0):

Hope help you:

```
$url = sprintf("http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=%s&email=%s", $token, $email);
```