# How can i get information of $name from HTML

Tags: php, html

Am a basic developer and want's some help that how can i get a PHP variable information using from HTML ?

Variable is declared in the same page. I have tried the following approach but getting error. Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
        $name = $_POST['namePHP'];
        $email = $_POST['emailPHP'];

$mail->Subject = 'Live-X || A New Registration Executed';
            $mail->Body = '<div>Respected <b>Sir</b></div>
                           <ul>
                                <li><b>Name: </b></li>'<?$name?>'                                      
                           </ul>

                           <div>Thanking You</div>';
            $mail->send();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `$mail->Body = "<div>Respected <b>Sir</b></div><ul><li><b>Name: </b></li>$name</ul><div>Thanking You</div>";`

Comment: you are missing several quotes or ; I don't know really what you are up to with this piece of code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape string with PHP and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555758/escape-string-with-php-and-html)

Comment: By the looks of it, the code posted above should produce a synthax error, because of this `<li><b>Name: </b></li>'<?$name?>'` line, because it does contain a synthax error there. You shuld really pay attention to what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to escape the string properly.

When using single quotes to create a string, you need to first end the string using a single quote, then 'switch' to a variable using a period (`.`), then to continue the string we use a period to allow us to re-open the string, again using a single quote.

```
$mail->Body = '<div>Respected <b>Sir</b></div>
               <ul>
                   <li><b>Name: </b></li>' . $name . '                                      
               </ul>
               <div>Thanking You</div>';
```

---

### Resources

[Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

[Escape string with PHP & HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555758/escape-string-with-php-and-html)

[Mixing variable with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-a-php-variable-with-a-string-literal)

Comment: Thanks so much Mark, now it's works fine.

Comment: No problem - if you could mark this answer as correct it would be appreciated.