# Page is not loading and error 500 appears after I add a string to my php Code

Tags: php, wordpress, string, woocommerce

I have a code that I add to my product page and my cart page.
but when I add script string code to it, the page doesn't load and I receive a 500 code error.
Can someone help me what is the problem? (I have a very limited knowledge of coding)
this is the document that I'm using as a reference.
https://developer.paybright.com/docs/prequalify-sdk-woocommerce
This is the code which works fine:

```
<?php
function pb_modal() {
    $pb_product_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true);
 
    $pb_product_format = number_format((float)$pb_product_price, 2, '.', '');
    echo "<script id='pb_prequalify' type='text/javascript' src='https://app.paybright.com/dist/sdk.js?public_key=INSERT_PUBLIC_KEY&financedamount=$$pb_product_format'></script>
<script>
    pb_prequalify_init();
</script>
<div id='paybright-widget-container'></div>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'pb_modal', 1);
 
?>
```

And whenever I change the script (the following code) I get the error 500:

```
<script>
     pb_prequalify_init({      
     triggerText:"Learn more",
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script>
     pb_prequalify_init({      
     triggerText:\"مجید دلبندم\",
  });
</script>
```

string started from `echo "<script id=pb_prequalify ....'`

if you want use `"` in this string you must use `\"` ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555758/escape-string-with-php-and-html)) ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999148/escaping-quotation-marks-in-php/19446792))

Every time you see a 500 error, just go to php settings and turn on the error display ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1))