# PHP variables in HTML string

Tags: php, html

I'm receiving some information from the AJAX form, and I need to generate a HTML email that will use some information from this form.

For example, I want to send something basic like

```
$msg = '<html><body>
     <p>Bla-bla-bla $information</p></body></html>'
```

How can I insert $information variable into paragraph without concatenation (using it is pretty painful, as the email HTML has pretty complex structure)?

Comment: Use double quotes instead? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double Or heredoc.

Comment: Take a look at phps `heredoc` feature: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: To piggy back off of @AbraCadaver you should do `$msg = "<html><body>
     <p>Bla-bla-bla $information</p></body></html>"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixing PHP variable with string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-php-variable-with-string-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add vars into variable without concat then maybe you are looking for something like this

```
$information = "Info";
$msg = "<html><body>
 <p>Bla-bla-bla $information</p></body></html>";
```

use your double quotes
Be aware if your var $information is array like this:

```
$information['info'] = "Info";
$information['id_info'] = 1;
$msg = "<html><body>
 <p>Bla-bla-bla $information[info]</p>
 <a href\"somepage.php?id=$information[id_info]\">Link</a></body></html>";
```

Double and single quotes

```
$email = 'someone@example.com';
$var = 'My email is $email'; // My email is $email
$var = "My email is $email"; // My email is someone@example.com
```

Comment: I like more like this to avoid unnecessary quotes :)

Comment: Thanks. Why would they ever make single and double quotes work different ways?

Comment: Oh there is lots of questions on stackoverflow about difference of quotes and you can find better answer there and more detailed then I can explain but in general in edit short difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are diffent ways to do it:

1) You can use "."

For example:

```
$msg = '<html><body>
 <p>Bla-bla-bla'. $information.'</p></body></html>';
```

2) You can use double quotes:

```
 $msg = "<html><body>
 <p>Bla-bla-bla $information</p></body></html>";
```