# Make a PHP variable the value of a form Input

Tags: html, forms, php-5.4

I want to make a PHP variable the value of a hidden form `input`. The form is inside of my PHP (I'm echoing the form), and nothing that I have tried works.

Here's my code:

```
echo '
<div id = "login">
<form action = "process.php" method = "POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" required>

<!-- Here is where I need to make my PHP variable the value: -->
<input type = "text" name = "referer" style = "display: none" value = "$variable"> 

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Enter">
</form>
</div>
';
```

---

Comment: `value = "' . $variable . '"> ` the text inside `' '` is treated as literal and php won't parse the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
?><!-- exit out of php into html-->
<div id = "login">
<form action = "process.php" method = "POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" required>

<!--Here is where I need to make my PHP variable the value:-->
<input type = "text" name = "referer" style = "display: none" value = "<?=$variable?>">

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Enter">
</form>
</div>
<?php // enter back into php
```

The `<?= ?>` is a [php short tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

---

Also, if you still want to use `echo`, try this:

```
//note: I changed the quotes
echo "
<div id = 'login'>
<form action = 'process.php' method = 'POST'>
Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'name' required>

<input type = 'text' name = 'referer' style = 'display: none' value = '$variable'> 

<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Enter'>
</form>
</div>
";
```

See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-php-variable-with-string-literal) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The usual string replacements `"$var"` don't work here , as it's all contained within a single quote string which doesn't allow for string replacements. You will have to concatenate manually

```
echo '
<div id = "login">
<form action = "process.php" method = "POST">
Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" required>

<input type = "text" name = "referer" style = "display: none" value = "' . $variable . '"> 

<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Enter">
</form>
</div>
';
```

Comment: in php `.` is used for [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) not `+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample here https://eval.in/506642

```
   echo "
<div id = 'login'>
<form action = 'process.php' method = 'POST'>
Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'name' required>

//Here's where I need to make my PHP variable the value:
<input type = 'text' name = 'referer' style = 'display: none' value = '$variable'> 

<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Enter'>
</form>
</div>
";
```