# PHP: Is there a difference between {$foo} and ${foo}

Tags: php

Sometimes you need to make clear to PHP what is actually the variable name.  I have discovered that a colleague and I had been doing it slightly differently.
Say you had a variable `$foo` and wanted to output that with _constant_string appended
I had been using

```
return "<input type='hidden' name='${foo}_constant_string' value='true' />";
```

whereas my colleague is using

```
return "<input type='hidden' name='{$foo}_constant_string' value='true' />";
```

(slightly contrived example to simplify it).

My quick tests don't reveal an obvious difference, but I am curious: Is there a difference?  Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Edit: 
My example above used strings but my question was more general - I should have explicitly said so.  I knew you could use curly braces for escaping, but hadn't found the specific point of if there was (in any situations) differences between the two ways  of using them.  I got the answer: there isn't for strings (which is what the "duplicate" post is about) but is for arrays and objects (thanks @dragoste).

Comment: I wonder why question is marked as duplicated. Maybe that guy didn't read the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems, there is no difference in any PHP version

```
    $foo = 'test';      
    var_dump("$foo");
    var_dump("{$foo}");
    var_dump("${foo}");
```

Test: https://3v4l.org/vMO2D

Anyway I do prefer `"{$foo}"` since I think it's more readable and works in many other cases where other syntax doesn't.

As an example let's try with object property accessing:

```
var_dump("$foo->bar"); //syntax error
var_dump("{$foo->bar}"); // works great
var_dump("${foo->bar}"); //syntax error
```

The same case are arrays.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no differentce.

```
// Works, outputs: This is fantastic
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";
```

[Php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

[Answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368897/4900669)

Another way use it for variable:

```
$foo = 'test';
$test = 'foo';
var_dump("{${$foo}}"); //string(3) "foo"
```

Or for array:

```
$foo = ['foo','test'];
var_dump("{$foo[0]}"); //string(3) "foo"
var_dump("${foo[1]}"); //string(4) "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the following statement -

```
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";
```

The output of both statements will be same.Please check following example-

```
$great = 'answer';
echo "This is {$great}"."\n";
echo "This is ${great}";

Output:-

This is answer
This is answer
```