# How to use variable inside table style for php email

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a variable inside a table style for php email but I can't make it work, please help

```php
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="background-color: {'$pnlclr1';}" cellpadding="0">';
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-a-php-variable-with-a-string-literal

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php: "_Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="background-color: '.$pnlclr1.';" cellpadding="0">';
```

no need of curly braces {}

Answer (score 1):

alternatively if you wrap the table tag in double quotes you can reference the variable without the need for concatenation

```
$message .= "<table rules='all' style='background-color:$pnlclr1' cellpadding='0'>";
```