# PHP with Loop Calculation

Tags: php, arrays, loops, calculation, background-subtraction

Can some help, don’t know how to solve this using loop in PHP

```
$pay = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15]; <br/>
$Capital = 1000; <br/>
```

I want the loop to achieve this result

```
1000-20 = 980 <br/>
980-40 = 940 <br/>
940-89 = 851 <br/>
851-300 = 551 <br/>
551-190 = 361 <br/>
361-15 = 346 <br/>
```

My code is:

```
$newbal = $Capital-$pay <br/>
for ($amount=$newbal; $amount>=$Capital; $amount-=$pay) {
    echo “{$amount} ”; <br/>
    $amount++; <br/>
}
```

My code is giving me this result:

```
1000-20 = 980 <br/>
1000-40 = 960 <br/>
1000-89 = 911 <br/>
1000-300 = 700 <br/>
1000-190 = 810 <br/>
1000-15 = 985 <br/>
```

Comment: Beware of coding in a Word Processor! The non ascii quotes like `“` will almost always cause you issues

Comment: The code you've shown produces an error. It does not produce the stated result: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f17d08c1ba4cd3bc28735fadeb470f643f87baa9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below, loops through the `$pays` array of integers.

each loop calculates the equation of `$captial` minus one of the integers and repeats, this is calculated and stored as a string in the `$lines` variable and at the end of each loop we recalculate the `$capital` and update the new value of `$capital` based on the previous calculation of `capital = capital - pay`

```php
<?php
    $pays = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15];
    $capital = 1000;

    $lines = [];

    foreach($pays as $pay){
        $lines[] = $capital . "-" . $pay . " = " . ($capital - $pay) . "<br/>";
        $capital -= $pay;
    }

    echo implode("\n", $lines);

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase is that good enough?

Comment: Thank you everyone, the code just solve my major problem in my programming knowledge

Answer (score 3):

A simple foreach loop over the `$pay` array with a `$balance` variable will allow a simple calculation inside the loop:

```php
$pay = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15];
$Capital = 1000; 

$balance = $Capital;
foreach ($pay as $p) {
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", $balance, $p, $balance = $balance - $p);
}                                          ########################
```

Output:

```
1000 - 20 = 980
980 - 40 = 940
940 - 89 = 851
851 - 300 = 551
551 - 190 = 361
361 - 15 = 346
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a complicated `for` loop, I'd recommend using a [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop over the `$pay` array and override `$Capital` after the `echo`.

We can use the `"${}"` syntax to [use variables inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368890/mixing-a-php-variable-with-a-string-literal).

---

Consider this example:

```php
<?php

$pay = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15];
$Capital = 1000; 
$newBal = $Capital;

foreach ($pay as $amount) {
    
    echo "${Capital} - ${amount} = " . ($Capital - $amount) . PHP_EOL;
    $Capital -= $amount; 
}
```

This will output the following as you can [test in this online demo](https://tio.run/##RY5PC4JAEMXPzqd4yB4KVNb@QLJJUAQdgrxHyCIbG5QuZUSIn33bLPEyMPN@770x2li7XBltiJiRb6Q4TniAGUeARRJgyt0WJ98xPwliG2kutbw6LuacCxAr1WvdHXpNEJ2ru5KFxqjLlA8weaueZT1GQx55qtAVfNb8DS1CsOZHtC7IR@ScfVM4mCNkuyzfHvaCvEFPe8B905K1Hw)

```
1000 - 20 = 980
980 - 40 = 940
940 - 89 = 851
851 - 300 = 551
551 - 190 = 361
361 - 15 = 346
```

---

We can do the assignment of `$Capital` inline, so I'd read:

```php
echo "${Capital} - ${amount} = " . ($Capital = $Capital - $amount) . PHP_EOL;
```

But for sake of readability, I'd add an extra line as in my example.

Answer (score 2):

You've somewhat overcomplicated it, and the code you showed produces errors rather than the output you stated.

You can achieve this more simply by looping through the `$pay` array directly with a `foreach`, and reducing the balance by the amount in the current pay item each time:

```
$pay = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15];
$capital = 1000;
$balance = $capital;
    
foreach ($pay as $item)
{
  $output = $balance."-".$item." = ";
  $balance -= $item;
  $output .= $balance;
  echo $output.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd1189f2d48b3428986ce52a087fb425ee970621

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$pay = [20, 40 , 89, 300, 190, 15];
$Capital = 1000;

foreach ($pay as $amount) {
    $newCap = $Capital - $amount; // calculate the new amount for output
    echo $Capital . ' - ' . $amount . ' = ' . $newCap . '<br>'; // output it
    $Capital = $newCap; // update the new amount for the next iteration
}
```

Online demo: https://3v4l.org/qmqcv